# Move circle and connecting points in Inkscape (manipulate graph plot)

Tags: vector, inkscape

I'm creating a network graph in R and exporting to Inkscape as a PDF (*see image below*). I would like to move the nodes around and have each node's edge (line connected to it) move with it. Is this possible to do in Inkscape?

My approach now is to ungroup the object, move a node and then try to move each edge and arrow object so that it lines up. But, this will take too much time. Is it possible to anchor one end of an object and move the other? Or is there a workaround to this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the file structure, it might be possible to just Shift+Click on the circle and the arrow with the node tool, select all nodes in the circle + the end node of the arrow, and then move that. 

There's a way to attach paths with a path effect, but I think that would take much longer to apply than to just use the node tool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes absolutely.

You can use the Create Diagram Connectors tool to make live connectors. Simply select the tool, mouse over a circle until you see the centre connector indicator, and click and drag to another circle connector indicator. You can then add arrow points in the stroke dialog.

You can then move the circles with the Select and Transform Objects tool (F1), and the connectors will follow the circles.

Obviously with this technique you can't automatically turn the arrows in your existing PDF into connectors, they'd have to be deleted first and then redrawn using the Diagram Connector tool. So, there's some manual work involved.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks this seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm not able to make the connector 'snap' (?) to the centre of the circle objects. Is there a setting/option preference that ensures objects can snap together to enable this approach?

Comment: @elliot You have to mouse over the centre indicator, then it changes colour, then click and drag to the other object's centre indicator, until it changes colour, then release the mouse. You can't see the colour change on the screen capture for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, the second object's centre box is not showing. So the 'connector' is not connecting to the second object (the first is working just like your example). I'm trying to identify this issue now -  any ideas? (though I know ediquite is to ask another question!).